# Azure Web App returning wrong SSL certificate

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have configured one IP-based SSL certificate for our app (e.g. mydomain.com) and a number of SNI certificates for customers to use at custom domains (e.g. www.theirdomain.com) plus a www for our site (www.mydomain.com). Those domains have CNAME records pointing to oursite.azurewebsites.net. We have been configured this way for quite a while with the exception of recently changing the spoketraining.com from SNI to IP because something over the weekend made that stop working.

We are suddenly having an issue where users are getting the wrong SSL certificates when they make requests from one of the CNAME URLs. They go to https://www.theirdomain.com and get the certificate for https://www.ourdomain.com. In Chrome this gives an ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. In Edge they get "There's a problem with this website's security certificate." Most users get it all the time, but it's not consistent. In our testing, we see that it mostly fails the first few times you go to the site, but then it may load part of the page and reject the API calls, and then it may work completely. Going to an incognito window usually makes it start again. When it does work, the browser shows the right certificate and that everything is good.

The way we've configured should work, right? Is there something more we should be doing to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with the exception of recently changing the spoketraining.com from SNI to IP because something over the weekend made that stop working.

Because the IP based SSL requires one dedicated IP Address and only one dedicated IP address can be created for a Web App, only one IP based SSL binding can be added. If you create multi IP based SSL binding, it will cause exception.

If you add a new IP based SSL binding, you need to change the other SSL binding to SNI SSL binding and you also need to remap all the CNAME records to ***sni.<appname>.azurewebsites.net*** instead of **<appname>.azurewebsites.net**.

Comment: I tried to set up a new custom domain so I could test if that would work. Unfortunately, when I try to do that, the Azure portal says it couldn't verify ownership. It wants a CNAME pointing to <appname>.azurewebsites.net and won't accept sni.<appname>.azurewebsites.net. Is there a way to get it to verify ownership? (In theory I could verify it and then change it, but that's not going to be an acceptable situation as we set up custom domains with clients.)

Comment: Ah, I did figure out that, while it's not documented for CNAME, creating a second CNAME for awverify.thecustomdomain.com does allow it to be verified. Trying sni.<appname>.azurewebsites.net now with clients to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Did changing the CNAME with sni prefix fix your issue? If yes, please mark this reply as answer. A thread which has been marked as answer will be easier searched. It will help other community members who encounter similar issue. If you have further questions about this topic, please feel free to let me know.